# Send Event to Datadog

Tags: json, go, struct, datadog

Unfortunately there is not an official Go Datadog API. I am currently using this one instead https://github.com/zorkian/go-datadog-api. Datadog forked the first version of it and recommend using it.

I am able to connect to my Dashboard:

```
    client := datadog.NewClient("...", "...")

    dash, err := client.GetDashboard(...)
    if err != nil {
      log.Fatalf("fatal: %s\n", err)
    }
```

But I do not know how to send create/track an event. This is my current approach but if fails badly.

```
    c := datadog.Client{}
    title := "Abc"
    e := datadog.Event{ Title: &title }
    c.PostEvent(&e)
```

From my understanding and the missing documentation, I would have to fill out some of these variables in this struct (https://github.com/zorkian/go-datadog-api/blob/master/events.go)

```
// Event is a single event.
// all fields will be filled out.
type Event struct {
  Id          *int     `json:"id,omitempty"`
  Title       *string  `json:"title,omitempty"`
  Text        *string  `json:"text,omitempty"`
  Time        *int     `json:"date_happened,omitempty"` // UNIX time.
  Priority    *string  `json:"priority,omitempty"`
  AlertType   *string  `json:"alert_type,omitempty"`
  Host        *string  `json:"host,omitempty"`
  Aggregation *string  `json:"aggregation_key,omitempty"`
  SourceType  *string  `json:"source_type_name,omitempty"`
  Tags        []string `json:"tags,omitempty"`
  Url         *string  `json:"url,omitempty"`
  Resource    *string  `json:"resource,omitempty"`
  EventType   *string  `json:"event_type,omitempty"`
}
```

Can you please help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code you posted:

```
c := datadog.Client{}
```

This seems to be creating an empty client object.

Shouldn't you be creating a client with your keys using `datadog.NewClient("...", "...")` as in the first code snippet you posted?

```
c := datadog.NewClient("...", "...")
```

Also, you should check the error returned as that will give you more hints to troubleshoot the issue:

```
_, err := c.PostEvent(&e)
if err != nil {
  log.Fatalf("fatal: %s\n", err)
}
```

`